# Capturing post request and save it to a list in SharePoint

Tags: 2013

We have a system that is built using Ektron, it will allow users to download documents that are available in SharePoint document library

Now everytime, user downloads document from Ektron, the system will generate a XML and post it back

What is the best option available in SharePoint to capture this request and save the xml that is posted by EKtron?

Basically  I am looking for something in SharePoint which can capture post requests and save it to a list